# How to convert JSON string values to lowercase in Python?

Tags: python

Have been struggling now couple hours to lowercase objects with Python. To use str lowercase function I need to convert it to the string. Can I someway convert it back to JSON? Because now there is just three objects in list which are strings.

My code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from typing import Optional, List

robots = [
    {'name': 'ABB', 'short': 'ABB'},
    {'name': 'Techman Robots', 'short': 'TM'},
    {'name': 'Mobile Industry Robots', 'short': 'MIR'},
]

@app.get('/robots')
def get_courses(lower: Optional[int] = None):
    cs = robots

    if lower == 1:
        cs = []
        for c in robots:
            joku = str(c).lower()
            cs.append(joku)

    return {'Robots': cs}
```

I want the results be like this:

```
    {'name': 'abb', 'short': 'abb'},
    {'name': 'techman robots', 'short': 'tm'},
    {'name': 'mobile industry robots', 'short': 'mir'},
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Sorry little language barrier. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`robots` is a `list` of `dictionaries`, so try the following

1. Iterate over dictionaries in the list `robots`
2. Iterate over keys in each `dictionary`
3. Get value of each `key` in dictionary, convert them to lowercase using `.lower()`
4. Save key and value in a new dictionary, append it to the new list

This should do it:

```py
robots = [
    {'name': 'ABB', 'short': 'ABB'},
    {'name': 'Techman Robots', 'short': 'TM'},
    {'name': 'Mobile Industry Robots', 'short': 'MIR'},
]

new_robots = []

for mdict in robots:
  new_dict = {}
  for key, value in mdict.items():
    new_dict[key] = value.lower()
  new_robots.append(new_dict)

print(robots)
```

**or in one line**

```
new_robots = [{key: value.lower() for key, value in mdict.items()} for mdict in robots]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'abb', 'short': 'abb'}, {'name': 'techman robots', 'short': 'tm'}, {'name': 'mobile industry robots', 'short': 'mir'}]
```

Comment: Your code is more simply. There is no appending. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly problem in your code is that there is not list for edited objects. If you are not using query parameter in url tou print lowercase results. You must do append to different list.

Comment: @JokoJoko do you want the result to be in a new list?

Comment: Yes. But I can done this myself. Thanks :) Make your answer right!

Comment: @JokoJoko, updated the answer, the one-liner approach should be the most simple

Comment: Is there a reason to use `new_dict.update({key: value.lower()})` instead of `new_dict[key] = value.slower()`?

Comment: @RoyCohen, Actually no, it happened when I expanded the one-liner code. I'll update it to assign since it is more readable. Thank-you for pointing it out. My guess is `update` could be more inefficient since a new `dict` object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with ast:

```
import ast

@app.get('/robots')
def get_courses(lower: Optional[int] = None): 
    cs = robots

    if lower == 1:
        cs = []
        for c in robots:
            finallyWorking= ast.literal_eval(str(c).lower())
            cs.append(finallyWorking) 

    return {'Robots': cs}
```